# Cannot Open Text File in Java

Tags: java, exception, text-files, bluej

I am using BlueJ, for reference.

The program compiles and runs fine.

The problem is that I am supposed to be opening a text file (and adding to it) but I am getting an exception and it says I cannot open said file.

The program is supposed to read and open "EmployeeData.txt":

```
S       Washington,George       000001      125000
H   MacDonald,Ronald        386218     7.80 true  40
H       Walton,Samuel           268517  8.21    false
H   Thomas,David            131313  9.45    true    38
H   Sanders,HarlandDavid    277651  8.72    false
S   Baron,James         368535  310236
```

This is a snippet of the output I currently get:

```
Cannot open EmployeeData.txt.
1) Add a salaried worker
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
2) Add an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
3) Add an hourly worker who has overtime allowed
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
H Smith,Will 345612 10.5 true 30
4) Add a worker that is already in the database
java.lang.RuntimeException: The Employee Is Not New
```

I am trying to read and open the text file in my main class, `WorkerApp`:

```
public class WorkerApp{
/**
* Reads the infile, runs tests, and prints the output.
*/
public static void  main (String args[]){
    Company company = new Company();
    try{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File("EmployeeData.txt"));
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String Employee[] = line.split(" ");
            String sorh = Employee[0];
            String name = Employee[1];
            String id = Employee[2];
            double salary = Double.parseDouble(Employee[3]);
            Employee e;
            if (Employee[0].equals("S")){
                e = new SalariedWorker(sorh, name, id, salary);}
            else {
                boolean overtime = Boolean.parseBoolean(Employee[4]);
                if(overtime){
                    int maxHours = Integer.parseInt(Employee[5]);
                     e = new HourlyWorker(sorh, name, id, salary, maxHours);
                }
                else{
                    e = new HourlyWorker(sorh, name, id, salary);
                }
            }
            company.add(e);
        }
    }catch (Exception err){
        System.out.println("Cannot open EmployeeData.txt.");
    }

    //Test Number 1
    System.out.println("1) Add a salaried worker");
    SalariedWorker SWorker1 = new SalariedWorker("S", "Moran,Blake", "123456", 260000);
    company.add(SWorker1);
    company.print();

    //Test Number 2
    System.out.println("2) Add an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed");
    HourlyWorker HWorker1 = new HourlyWorker("H", "Bob,Billy", "654321", 15);
    company.add(HWorker1);
    company.print();

    //Test Number 3
    System.out.println("3) Add an hourly worker who has overtime allowed");
    HourlyWorker HWorker2 = new HourlyWorker("H", "Smith,Will", "345612", 10.5, 30);
    company.add(HWorker2);
    company.print();

    //Test Number 4
    System.out.println("4) Add a worker that is already in the database");
    try{
        company.add(SWorker1);
    }catch(Exception err){
        System.out.println(err);
        System.out.println();
    }   

    //Test Number 5
    System.out.println("5) Print the sorted list");
    company.print();

    //Test Number 6
    System.out.println("6) Remove a worker who is NOT in the list");
    company.remove("Brooks,Phil");
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 7
    System.out.println("7) Remove a worker who is the first in the list ");
    company.remove("Moran,Blake");
    company.print();
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 8
    System.out.println("8) Find a worker who is the middle of the list");
    int index = company.find("Bob,Billy");
    System.out.println("Found at "+ index);
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 9
    System.out.println("9) Find a worker who is NOT in the list");
    index = company.find("Harrison,Ford");
    System.out.println("Found at "+ index);
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 10
    System.out.println("10) Find the weekly salary of a worker who is salaried");
    System.out.println(SWorker1.FindSalary());
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 11
    System.out.println("11) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed [50 hours]");
    System.out.println(HWorker1.FindSalary(50));
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 12
    System.out.println("12) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed [50 hours]");
    System.out.println(HWorker2.FindSalary(50));
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 13
    System.out.println("13) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed [20 hours]");
    System.out.println(HWorker2.FindSalary(20));
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 14
    System.out.println("14) Print the sorted list");
    company.print();

    //Test Number 15
    System.out.println("\n15) End the process");
} 
}
```

This is my `Company` class if it helps:

```
public class Company{
private Employee[] employeeArray;
private final int InitialCapacity = 7;
private int employCount;

/**
* Creates the employee array and sets employCount to 0.
*/
public Company(){
    employeeArray = new Employee[InitialCapacity];
    employCount = 0;
}

/**
* Finds an employee in the list.
*/
public int find(String name){
    for (int i = 0; i < employCount; i++){
        if (employeeArray[i].getName().equals(name)){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

/**
* Adds an employee to the list.
*/
public int add(Employee employ){
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < employCount; index++){
        int result = employeeArray[index].getName().compareTo(employ.getName());
        if(result == 0){
            throw new RuntimeException ("The Employee Is Not New");
        }
    }

    if (employeeArray.length == employCount){
        expand();
    }

    employeeArray[index] = employ;
    employCount++;
    return index;
}

/**
* Removes an employee to the list.
*/
public void remove(String name){
    int index = find(name);
    if (index == -1){
        System.out.println("The Employee is not Found");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < employCount - 1; i++){
        employeeArray[i] = employeeArray[i + 1];
    }

    employCount--;
}

/**
* Prints the list.
*/
public void print(){
    if(employCount == 0){
        System.out.println("The List is Empty");
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < employCount; i++){
        System.out.println(employeeArray[i]);
    }
}

/**
* Expands the list.
*/
private void expand(){
    Employee[] newArray = new Employee[employeeArray.length + InitialCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++){
        newArray[i] = employeeArray[i];
    }

    employeeArray = newArray;
}
}
```

It should be noted that there are three other classes, `Employee`, `HourlyWorker`, and `SalariedWorker`. The ladder two are subclasses of Employee, but they aren't important in terms of reading the text file, so I excluded them from this post.

Hopefully I can get some assistance.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of printing `System.out.println("Cannot open EmployeeData.txt.");` in your `catch` statement, try to print the stack trace of your `Exception`. Wanna bet it's a `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: That gives me an `java.lang.NumberFormatException`,actually. Still unsure how to proceed, though.

Comment: Check your `Number.parseXXX` statements and adjust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really dangerous to write

```
catch (Exception err){
    System.out.println("Cannot open EmployeeData.txt.");
}
```

or anything like it, because it means you throw away all the information about what caused the error.  At the very least, you should print out the stack trace of the error, so that you can investigate what happened.

Try adding

```
err.printStackTrace();
```

inside the `catch` block and read what it prints.  That should tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: That gives me an `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. Still unsure how to proceed, though.

Comment: OK, but what's important is that the first line of the stack trace will tell you what line the NumberFormatException occurred on.  Basically,  you've got some text that isn't a number, and you're trying to treat it like a number - like read it into an `int` variable or a `double` variable or something like that.  Have a look at your input file, and see if there are words where there should be numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few errors in your code like `System.out.println(employeeArray[i]);` which will print out the some memory nonsense so I went and cleaned up your code a bit and added the stack trace for the `FileNotFoundException`. He is my solution of the program you made.

```
package helper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class WorkerApp {
    /**
     * Reads the infile, runs tests, and prints the output.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Company company = new Company();
        Employee emp;

        try {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream("EmployeeData.txt")));
            String line;
            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] current = line.split(" ");
                emp = new Employee(current[0], current[1], current[2],
                        current[3]);

                if (emp.getSorh().equals("S")) {
                    emp = new SalariedWorker(emp.getSorh(), emp.getName(),
                            emp.getId(), emp.getSalary());
                } else {

                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(current[4])) {

                        emp = new HourlyWorker(emp.getSorh(), emp.getName(),
                                emp.getId(), emp.getSalary(),
                                Integer.parseInt(current[5]));
                    } else {
                        emp = new HourlyWorker(emp.getSorh(), emp.getName(),
                                emp.getId(), emp.getSalary());
                    }
                }
                company.add(emp);
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open EmployeeData.txt.");
            System.out.println("Got an IOException: " + err.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Company Class

```
package helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Company {
    private ArrayList<Employee> comp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    private int employeeCount = comp.size();

    public void add(Employee emp) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Employee employee : comp) {
            if (employee.getName().equals(emp)) {
                System.out.println("Employee is not new");
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!found) {
            comp.add(emp);
            employeeCount = comp.size();
        }

    }

    public void print() {
        if (comp.size() >= 0) {
            for (Employee employee : comp) {
                System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employee.getName());
                System.out.println("Employee Id: " + employee.getId());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have no Employees");
        }

    }

    public void remove(String emp) {
        int found = find(emp);
            if(!(found == -1){
            comp.remove(found);
            employeeCount = comp.size();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No such employee exists");
        }
    }

    public int find(String emp) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Employee employee : comp) {
            if (employee.getName().equals(emp)) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

Employee Class

```
package helper;

public class Employee {
    private String sorh;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String sorh, String name, String id, String salary) {

        this.sorh = sorh;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.salary = Double.parseDouble(salary);
    }

    public String getSorh() {
        return sorh;
    }

    public void setSorh(String sorh) {
        this.sorh = sorh;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

SalariedWorker Class

```
package helper;

public class SalariedWorker extends Employee {



    public SalariedWorker(String sorh, String name, String id, double salary) {
        super(sorh, name, id, String.valueOf(salary));
    }

}
```

HourlyWorker  CLass

```
package helper;

public class HourlyWorker extends Employee{
    private int maxHours;

    public HourlyWorker(String sorh, String name, String id, double salary) {
        super(sorh, name, id, String.valueOf(salary));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public HourlyWorker(String sorh, String name, String id, double salary,
            int maxHours) {
        super(sorh, name, id, String.valueOf(salary));
        this.maxHours = maxHours;
    }

}
```

Comment: This spits out: `Cannot open EmployeeData.txt.
Got an IOException: For input string: "Washington,George"`
in my output, unfortunately